# List of Map Service Software

Tags: web-mapping, wms, web-service

I am curious as to what GIS server software is out there. I have used a few different ones and am building a list of them. If you know of any others please mention it below because I would like to check it them out. I have listed the software that I am already aware of below.

**GIS Server Software:**
***Name*** || ***Source*** || ***License*** 
[MapServer](http://mapserver.org/) || Open || [MIT-style license](http://mapserver.org/copyright.html#license)
[GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) || Open || [GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/License)
[TileStache](http://tilestache.org/) || Open || BSD License
[TileCache](http://tilecache.org/) || Open || BSD license
[Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) || Open || [LGPL (Lesser General Public Licence)](http://mapnik.org/licence/)
[ArcGIS for Server](http://www.esri.com/products/index.html#server_gis_panel) || Closed || [ESRI](http://www.esri.com/legal/licensing/software-license.html)
[A Custom Server Built on GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/about.html) || Open || LGPL
[MapZoom](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~gildea/Map/) || Open || ???
[GLG Map Server](http://www.genlogic.com/download.html) || Closed || ???
[Deegree](http://www.deegree.org/) || Open || LGPL
[Geomajas](http://www.geomajas.org/) || Open || [AGPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html)
[Mapguide Open Source](http://mapguide.osgeo.org/) || Open ||LGPL
[GeoMedia Map Publisher](http://www.intergraph.com/sgi/downloads.aspx?assetid=165) || Closed || Intergraph
[MapViewer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/mapviewer/overview/index.html) || Closed || Oracle
[Mapbender](http://projects.mapbender.osgeo.org/) || Open || [GNU GPL and Simplified BSD license](http://trac.osgeo.org/mapbender/browser/trunk/mapbender/license/license.txt)
Hopefully that list helps others who are also looking for options. Also if I have mistakenly added one please let me know. I haven't tried most of packages on the list so if you have used any of them please let me know if you would recommend it and how your experience with the software was.

**Question 1:** Do you know of any other GIS Map Service Software?

**Question 2:** How was your experience with a GIS Map Service Software package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[QGIS Mapserver](http://karlinapp.ethz.ch/qgis_wms/index.html) || Open || GPL

Answer (score 4):

[Manifold IMS](http://www.manifold.net/info/ims.shtml) || Closed || [Manifold](http://www.manifold.net/admin/licensing.shtml)

Sorry, I don't have any experience with this one. Just trying to help build a complete list.

Answer (score 3):

One place to look is on the OGC web site - http://www.opengeospatial.org/resource/products/byspec and then select which version of the WMS spec you are interested in. I don't know how reliable the list is as it filled in by the developers of the software but I'd expect that if you went to the effort of writing a WMS then you'd register it there.

The list is divided into 2 categories, implementations and compliant products. The compliant products have been through OGC certification testing to ensure compliance. This is indicated by a green check mark and a certification test date.

Answer (score 2):

[FME Server](http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-technology/fme-server/) || Closed || [Safe Software](http://www.safe.com)

Answer (score 0):

Another GIS software is Mapline (https://mapline.com). If you like fast geocoding, try using their mapping service.

Answer (score 0):

[MapSurfer.NET](http://mapsurfernet.com) || Closed || [Freeware](http://mapsurfernet.com/docs/license)