# How to index large VRT files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal, pyqgis, vrt

I have a large number of small tiles merged into a single VRT. The rasters are only viewed at large scale, so only a few of them are visible at the same time. The map refresh in qgis is slowing down however, as the number of tiles in the vrt increases. Is there any indexing of raster possible in the vrt format itself or perhaps inside pyqgis (manipulating the raster layer that links to my .vrt).

Comment: Perhaps some of the answers in this post might help: [Best way to manage large number of geoTiff rasters](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12525/best-way-to-manage-large-number-of-geotiff-rasters).

Comment: Seen that. WMS is not an option, its a local desktop application... Also way too much time would be spent retiling additional tiles i think.

Comment: Only other thing I could think of would be creating pyramids :)

Comment: Also no use, the zoom level at which my raster are used is below the pyramidss, they're not even used.

Comment: Your analysis is right and VRT does not support any kind of indexing. There is an open GDAL ticket about this https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5762. However, there may be a workaround. It should be possible to create a set of smaller .VRT files which contain a reasonable amount of images and then build another vrt from the first generation .VRT files. Sort of a hand written b-tree index.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, i ll try with postgis raster...

Comment: No good with postgis raster, theres no real support in qgis... db manager hangs. Im trying with a large VRT, hosting a bunch of smaller

Comment: In the end, i went with larger tiles (equals less tiles) and ecw format. Its not scalable, but it works for our case.

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing the comments so this question can be marked as answered:

VRT does not support any kind of indexing. There is an open GDAL ticket about this http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5762. However, there may be a workaround. It should be possible to create a set of smaller .VRT files which contain a reasonable amount of images and then build another vrt from the first generation .VRT files. Sort of a hand written b-tree index.

ECW might be an alternative, depending on the use case.