# List of WMS Servers

Tags: wms, server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GIS Map Service Software](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12493/gis-map-service-software)

I'm experimenting with some applications and I would like to know what are our options for wms servers, such as MapServer and Geoserver.

Do you guys know any other implementations? OS preferred, but private is ok too.

Can we create a comprehensive list of WMS server software?